# landoop kafka dev schema registry

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

I have been trying to use the following docker-compose file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  # this is our kafka cluster.
  kafka-cluster:
    image: landoop/fast-data-dev:cp3.3.0
    environment:
      ADV_HOST: 127.0.0.1         # Change to 192.168.99.100 if using Docker Toolbox
      RUNTESTS: 0                 # Disable Running tests so the cluster starts faster
      FORWARDLOGS: 0
      SAMPLEDATA: 0
    ports:
      - 2181:2181                 # Zookeeper
      - 3030:3030                 # Landoop UI
      - 8082-8084:8081-8083       # REST Proxy, Schema Registry, Kafka Connect ports
      - 9581-9585:9581-9585       # JMX Ports
      - 9092:9092                 # Kafka Broker
```

This starts a kafka cluster in my local machine.
Now it works well when sending messages to localhost:9092 with a custom serializer. I am now trying to add support for apache avro by using the schema registry that is packed with the docker image. I have created the schema inside the schema registry and I have a java object coming from an avsc file that I am using inside the kafkatemplate send method.  I added the following line to connect to the schema registry server:

```
configProps.put(KafkaAvroSerializerConfig.SCHEMA_REGISTRY_URL_CONFIG,"http://localhost:8081");
```

This results in the following exception:

```
org.apache.kafka.common.errors.SerializationException: Error serializing Avro message
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:107) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:399) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:224) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:609) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:569) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClient.java:242) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:341) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.java:362) ~[na:na]
```

I think this is an authentication issue, so I've been looking at the following documentation for instructions: https://hub.docker.com/r/landoop/fast-data-dev

So far I can't find a default username and password to perform the authentication against the schema registry, or a way to create my own user and password.

Any help will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the code is running on the host, you aren't forwarding `localhost:8081` from the host - refer `8082-8084:8081-8083`.

Unless you have some error, you should use direct matching ports on the host to the container

---

If are running code in a container, you need to use `http://kafka-cluster:8081` while running the application container on the same network bridge